# Check String if it has an ascii like "/" and ":" using VBA

Tags: vba

Here's my code but i want to know how will I know if the string has special characters like '/' or ':'.Many Thanks. Much great if you can edit my function.

```
Do Until EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, LineFromFile <-----LineFromFile is the string
     If HasCharacter(LineFromFile) = True Then
        MsgBox "This File should be uploaded to FilePath2"
      Else
     Blah Blah Blah.......
```

This is my function

```
Function HasCharacter(strData As String) As Boolean
   Dim iCounter As Integer

   For iCounter = 1 To Len(strData)
     If ....(Don't know what to say) Then
       HasCharacter = True
       Exit Function
     End If
   Next iCounter
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
Function HasCharacter(strData As String) As Boolean

     If InStr(strData, "/") > 0 Or InStr(strData, ":") > 0 Then
       HasCharacter = True
     Else
       HasCharacter = False
     End If
End Function
```

The function `InStr` returns the position of the string if found, else it returns 0.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply:

```
if strData like "*[:/]*" then 
    msgbox "This File should be uploaded to FilePath2"
else
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `InStr(stringToCheck, characterToFind)`

```
Function HasCharacter(strData As String) As Boolean
  If InStr(strData, "/") + InStr(strData, ":") > 0 Then
    HasCharacter = True
  End If
End Function
```

`InStr` returns 0 if the character cannot be found in the string. In this case, I add the positions of both special characters together. If the sum of these positions is greater than 0, we know  that it contains at least one special character. You can separate this logic if you'd like.

Comment: I came across an error "ByRef Argument type mismatch" and it highlights LineFromFile in `If HasCharacter(LineFromFile) = True Then` Any advice with regards to this error? Thanks again

Comment: @Patrick It expects a `string`. Are you passing in a `string()` or `string`? You might have to add the `iCounter` piece back in, if you're passing in `string()`.

Comment: Hi grovesNL Can you kindly check my whole code...I'm really stuck. Advance thanks from me.I'll open another question and put the link here

Comment: @Patrick If it's related to this issue, you can just edit your original post here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple characters then can also invert the checking and its easier to edit than multiple or statements

```
Function HasCharacter(strData As String) As Boolean
   Dim iCounter As Integer

  For iCounter = 1 To Len(strData)
    If Instr ("/:", Mid (strData, iCounter, 1)) > 0 Then
      HasCharacter = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next iCounter
```

End Function